# Who did Finnick marry in the final Hunger Games movie?

Tags: the-hunger-games, the-hunger-games-mockingjay-2

Bare with me on this one; I am watching the final Hunger Games movie, *Mockingjay, Part 2*, and trying to understand based on my less than crisp memory of the prior films.

One of the characters from an earlier Hunger Games film was Finnick Odair, former Hunger Games winner turned male sex slave, who was forced to compete with the other survivors/winners in the 2nd Hunger Games movie, *Catching Fire*.

He gets married in the fourth movie, *Mockingjay, Part 2*.

[image]

Who is this person he's marrying? Isn't that the woman who dressed up like a tree for one of the parades and who got naked in the elevator with the other characters in *Catching Fire*?

Comment: His name is Finnick Odair.

Comment: I said "his"... the "jiggalo" is Finnick. ;)

Comment: That's his wife.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

His name is Finnick Odair and he marries [Annie Cresta](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Annie_Cresta), a victor from District 4.

> Annie Cresta is a victor from District 4. Annie is known for winning the 70th Hunger Games. She is the wife of the late Finnick Odair and the mother of their child.

She was practically cut out of the films and only plays a minor part in the books (as far as I can remember).

You're conflating her with Jena Malone's character, [Johanna Mason](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Johanna_Mason). She's the one who dresses up as a tree and strips in the elevator.

Comment: Was she also the one who dressed up like a tree and changed clothes in front of the others in the elevator in the 2nd movie?

Comment: No. That was Jena Malone's character, Johanna Mason.

Comment: Oooo ok. Got it, thank you! I think he should've married Johanna instead. Just my opinion ;)

Comment: @Hack-R That young lady has way too much attitude.

Answer (score 5):

That is **Annie Cresta from District 4**, where Finnick is also from. She was the winner of the 70th Hunger Games. Finnick, as the District 4 winner from the 65th Hunger Games, became a mentored for other District 4 tributes, specifically Annie, and that's how they fell in love.

During *Catching Fire*, when the special Quarter Quell placed the previous winners in the Reaping, Annie was picked as the District 4 female tribute. Luckily, Annie's other mentor (who also mentored Finnick) was Mags, the female tribute who won the 11th Hunger Games. Mags basically raised Finnick, and volunteered as tribute to save Annie for both Annie's and Finnick's sake. Much like how Katniss volunteered for Primrose and Peeta for Haymitch.

[image]

In *Mockingjay Part 1*, Finnick points out that Annie was arrested by the Capitol just to blackmail/extort Finnick. Even before the 2nd Rebellion started, President Snow had threatened Finnick with killing Annie if Finnick didn't do what Snow wanted. And that ended up being a sex slave to anyone that would pay Snow for Finnick. Literal child prostitution. ***The other tribute, who you confused Annie for, Johanna Mason from District 7***, had her whole family killed by President Snow when she ***wouldn't be a sex slave***. Since Snow couldn't just kill her after that, she was left alone until the Quarter Quell. **Finnick had rather been a slave than see Annie or Mags killed.** Much like how Snow was forcing Katniss to be with Peeta after the 74th Hunger Games. Finnick ended up using his position to gather secrets about Snow and the Capitol.

[image]

At the end of **Mockingjay Part 1** Annie, the redhead, is (allowed to be) *rescued* by District 13's commandos who went in to rescue Peeta and the other captured tributes. Finnick and Annie are reunited back at District 13's medical unit. Where Peeta attempts to choke Katniss to death. Johanna is also rescued. She's the bald one in the hospital bed.

Seeing the two *Catching Fire* images next to each other, it is easy to understand why you'd confuse them. Annie and Johanna do share a small resemblance.

Comment: that's a very good answer! Why couldn't President Snow just kill Johanna for not being an escort (and why was pimping out the victors so important to him? did he do this to Katniss?)? Just wondering.

Comment: @Hack-R He probably would have, if he hadn't decided Katniss was too dangerous and had to die. Of course... that plan didn't go so well for him.

Comment: @Hack-R he didn't kill the tributes because the Capitol citizens love the tributes. If they found out he was doing it, it would be political suicide. And Katniss had the star crossed lovers thing with Peeta, so he couldn't sell them either. Which is what Haymitch tells Katniss on the train in Catching Fire. She's stuck pretending to love Peeta on camera for the rest of their lives, even though she doesn't love him like that yet. If they don't pretend, Snow would have their families killed.

Comment: @cde ooooo. OK that makes sense. Except for why he pimps them out. Just an extra stream of revenue and an insult to the districts, I suppose.

Comment: @Hack-R political power. He trades Finnick to powerful or wealthy people as a gift or for money/favors. He also does it to put the victors in their place, as his playthings. See https://angelmatos.net/2013/02/25/the-hunger-games-male-prostitution/ for a good overview.